# add_image_size cropping changes on Mobile devices

Tags: thumbnails, mobile, images

I have images that are being cropped by wordpress with

```
add_image_size( 'centerright', 320, 320, array( 'right', 'center' ) );
```

But on mobile, it seems showing those same thumbnails but the default version (center, center).

How can I make it show the same thumbnail on mobile? Please let me know if you need my site url.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Empty both browsers caches and check again.

Comment: What is the content of the img tag?

Answer (score 0):

First deactivate any caching plugins you may have and delete their caches. Then delete all browser data on all devices. This is the most probably cause for this. On reactivation, things should get back to normality.